# How to turn a 2 column list into a responsive dropdown Bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I take a two-column list and make it a responsive dropdown? Alternatively, does anybody know of an online tutorial that can put me on the right path?

I need to make the left sidebar dropdown at the same point my top nav drops down. Using Bootstrap on [this](http://skeeterz71.com/auto/test-dropdown-list.html) page.

P.S. I found a bootstrap code that I tried, but it is a continuous dropdown. Maybe somebody knows how to modify it to display the entire list at full screen?

http://skeeterz71.com/auto/2-test-dropdown-list.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See if this mega menu helps.......

http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/